# How to start another activity after login success

Tags: android

how do i start an activity after my login activity success.. i had tried  this , [how to start an activity after my login Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039683/how-to-start-an-activity-after-my-login-activity) but doesn't seem to be working for me. i have put my login activity in my main.. then my alert message in a php script .. 
Here is my `backgroundtask` coding:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("register"))
    {
    String name = params[1];
    String user_name = params[2];
    String user_pass = params [3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (method.equals("login"))
    {
       String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
      String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
              URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
              response+= line ;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(result.contains("Login Success")) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,NewActivity.class);
        getApplicationContext.startActivity(i);
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }


 }
}
```

please help me with this... its been a week  that i had been trying to solve this .. tq

Comment: i had tried this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437527/how-to-start-a-new-activity-after-login-success but still doest work for me

Comment: as now, what do you get after you login successful?

Comment: You're not starting an `Activity` anywhere. What are you expecting to happen, and what is happening?

Comment: `context.startActivity(new Intent(context,anotherActivity.class));` isn't it ?????

Comment: Phan Văn Linh ya im getting login successful alert after log in . its fucntioning well . but i need to start an activity after that ..

Comment: Mike M. this is my initial coding .. as i said . i have tried the two method that solved both of the questions i stated but not seem to be working for me ....

Comment: Then you need to show what you've tried and how it fails. Another generic example probably isn't going to help you, if the other two didn't.

Comment: @AmirulAsyraf try my edit answer

Comment: @DaminiMehra Don't edit answers into the question.

Comment: @DaminiMehra the answer that u provided in the edit is the one that i had tried in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437527/how-to-start-a-new-activity-after-login-success..... its not working for me . if i applies the code my login successful message also not be showing ...

Comment: this is my MainActivity.java and my login.php script image .http://imgur.com/a/o7F9J please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Login Process, you try to debug what value of 'response' (Line 66) when login is success

That is 2 way to debug 'response'

1. Using Debugging Tool with BreakPoint
2. before return response, put below code and watch your Logcat.

   Log.e("CODE", "response : " + response);

When you know content of response, change your onPostExecute to below code, and replace {$CONTENTS YOU DEBUGGED} to debugging result.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if(result.contains("Hello") { 
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SomethingClass.class);
        ctx.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

---

Edit))

The response pattern is Hello Welcome + $user. so, when response contains 'Hello', It will move another Activity. That's it.

Comment: i do not find the " CONTENTS YOU DEBUGGED" as i place my log in alerts in a php script.. sry im really noob at android

Comment: Not php source, just your code. Can you post alertdialog picture using imgur? I'll help you

Comment: It seems to be return Hello <username> . replace else if(result. equals("{$CONTRNTS YOU DEBUGGED")) { to else if(result.contains("Hello")) { . This will work for you.

Comment: this is my MainActivity.java and my login.php script image .imgur.com/a/o7F9J please help me –

Comment: the startActivity(i) could noy be resolve.. theres an error to it ... sry im really bad at this

Comment: use context for that. 
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,anotherActivity.class)); isn't it ????? –

Comment: It seems to sperated class. Move DownloadTask class's content to MainActivity. (merge two file). because, startActivity(i) exist in Activity class.

Comment: I found some easy point. Replcae startActivity(i) and Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomethingClass.class) . just like [this](https://gist.github.com/WindSekirun/48292c3ddee010e18c6b9d67dd2ab81f) Two class is separated. That's why you using ctx instead MainActivity.class. more info about Context(ctx) is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: @WindSekirun replace the startActivity(i) with ??

Comment: just look at my [link](https://gist.github.com/WindSekirun/48292c3ddee010e18c6b9d67dd2ab81f) Line 79~80

Comment: @WindSekirun It worksss magically .. Ty for your help . i really appriciate it ..

Answer (score 1):

you must return String "Login success" on void doInBackGround, and then create new condition on void onPostExecute;

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equals("Login success")) 
        { 
            startActivity(new Intent(yourCURRENTactivity.this, yourNEXTactivity.class)); 
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

     }
    }
```

Comment: the startActivity doesnt seem to be acknowledge... sry i really dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have given application context in intent which is not right. It should be currentactivity and then next switching activity. Please see the code below

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
{
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(result.contains("Login Success")) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent(currentactivity.this,NewActivity.class);
    getApplicationContext.startActivity(i);
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}


}
```

Comment: this is what i get when i tried to apply ur code http://imgur.com/jZShp4f it said that MainActivity is not enclosing class.